# Bulk renaming files with different extensions in order using powershell

Tags: powershell

is there a way to bulk rename items such that a folder with the items arranged in order would have their name changed into numbers with zero padding regardless of extension?

for example, a folder with files named:

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
file4.png
file5.png
file6.png
file7.png
file8.jpg
file9.jpg
file10.mp4
```

would end up like this:

```
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
04.png
05.png
06.png
07.png
08.jpg
09.jpg
10.mp4
```

i had a script i found somewhere that can rename files in alphabetical order. however, it seems to only accepts conventionally bulk renamed files (done by selecting all the files, and renaming them such that they read "file (1).jpg" etc), which messes up the ordering when dealing with differing file extensions. it also doesn't seem to rename files with variations in their file names. here is what the code looked like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Directory -Filter file* | % { 
    $matched = $_.BaseName -match "\((?<number>\d+)\)"
    if (-not $matched) {break;}
    [int]$number = $Matches["number"]
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($number.ToString("000"))$($_.Extension)"
}
```

Comment: Certainly, yes, although sorting the files by name would put `file10.mp4` between `file1.jpg` and `file2.jpg`, not at the end, so the numbers would have to be parsed first.  What problem are you having with this?

Comment: You should [include that code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71390251/edit) in the question, as it helps to show what you're trying to do and where you're at in accomplishing that.  What do you mean by "conventionally bulk renamed files"?  Where they all have the same extension?

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews code has been included and a definition for conventionally bulk renamed files has been somewhat established

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to rename the files based on the ending digits of their `BaseName` you can use `Get-ChildItem` in combination with `Where-Object` for filtering them and then pipe this result to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2) using a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters).

Needles to say, this code **does not handle file collision**. If there is more than one file with the same ending digits and the same extension this **will error out**.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter file* | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\d+$' } |
Rename-Item -NewName {
    $basename = '{0:00}' -f [int][regex]::Match($_.BaseName, '\d+$').Value
    $basename + $_.Extension
}
```

To test the code you can use the following:

```
@'
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
file4.png
file5.png
file6.png
file7.png
file8.jpg
file9.jpg
file10.mp4
'@ -split '\r?\n' -as [System.IO.FileInfo[]] | ForEach-Object {
    $basename = '{0:00}' -f [int][regex]::Match($_.BaseName, '\d+$').Value
    $basename + $_.Extension
}
```

Comment: the intent was to take the names of all files in a folder in alphabetical arrangement regardless of extension and rename them into numbers with zero padding, such that the files with ascending names like "3w874f.png", "7d6bz9t8n.txt", "325n78ws.jpg", and "qoe89b7.mp4" get renamed into "1.png", "2.txt", "3.jpg", and "4.mp4". is there a way that it can be achieved?

Comment: @dedddoo230 I believe Theo's answer is doing what you're looking for. If so, please accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the number of files found in the folder to create the appropriate 'numbering' format for renaming them.

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File) | Sort-Object Name
# depending on the number of files, create a formating template 
# to get the number of leading zeros correct. 
# example: 645 files would create this format: '{0:000}{1}'
$format = '{0:' + '0' * ($files.Count).ToString().Length + '}{1}' 

# a counter for the index number
$index  = 1 
# now loop over the files and rename them
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName ($format -f $index++, $file.Extension) -WhatIf
}
```

<sup>The `-WhatIf` switch is a safety measure. With this, no file gets actually renamed, you will only see in the console what *WOULD* happen. Once you are content with that, remove the `-WhatIf` switch from the code and run again to rename all your files in the folder</sup>